# Why does boost::asio appear to do nothing

Tags: c++, boost-asio, irc

I'm trying to implement the irc protocol in a very basic manner. My first attempt is to use boost::asio and connect to a server and read the motd. AFAIK the motd is sent to every client when they connect. I have made the following test program and it seems to not do anything. It's not a very good piece of code but this is all I have after several frustrating hours.

```
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>
#include <queue>



class IrcConnection
{
public:
    IrcConnection(const std::string& server, int port, boost::function<void (const std::string&)> onMessage, boost::asio::io_service& io_service): s(server), p(port), onM(onMessage), ios(io_service), socket(io_service)
    {
    }
    void connect() 
    {
        somethingHappened = false;
        //DNS stuff
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver resolver(ios);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::query query(s , "0");
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator iter = resolver.resolve(query);
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver::iterator end;

        boost::system::error_code error;

        while(iter != end)
        {
            boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint = iter->endpoint();
            endpoint.port(p);
            socket.close();
            socket.connect(endpoint, error);
            iter++;
        }
        if(error)
        {
            std::cout << "ERROR" << std::endl;
            std::cout << error << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "Connected to: " << socket.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << std::endl; 

        //read from the socket until a space is found
        boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, currentData, ' ', boost::bind(&IrcConnection::onReceiveFinished, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
    void disconnect() 
    {
        socket.close();
    }
    void send(int priority, const std::string& message) 
    {
    }
bool somethingHappened;

private:
    std::string s;
    int p;
    boost::function<void (const std::string&)> onM;
    boost::asio::io_service& ios;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket;
    std::priority_queue<std::string> outQueue;
    boost::asio::streambuf currentData;


    void onReceiveFinished(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if(error)
        {
            disconnect();
            std::cout << "ERRORRRR" << std::endl;
            std::cout << error << std::endl;
        }

        std::cout << "STUFF IS OCCURING" << std::endl;
        somethingHappened = true;

         std::istream stream(&currentData);
         std::string data;
         std::getline(stream, data);

         boost::asio::async_read_until(socket, currentData, ' ', boost::bind(&IrcConnection::onReceiveFinished, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
         ios.dispatch(boost::bind(onM, data));
    }


};


void onMe(const std::string& x)
{
    std::cout << "MESSAGE" << std::endl;
    std::cout << x << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service ios;
    std::string server = "irc.efnet.org";
    int port = 6667;

    IrcConnection x(server, port, onMe, ios);

    x.connect();

    while(!x.somethingHappened)
    {
        //
    }

    return 0;

}
```

The program attempts to connect to irc.efnet.org and read until a space is sent and then spits that data out to the terminal. However I run this and all that is printed is the ip address of what I connected to and then the program does not terminate.

What do I need to do to get my indented behavior?

Comment: asynchronous IO frameworks, C++, and winders, all rolled into one question... what a nightmare :D

Comment: @Matt: ASIO when used correctly is a very fantastic library, nothing in C++ or even in other languages comes close to what it has to offer. Learn to use it before complaining. :)

Comment: @Hippicoder: I'll admit I've never used it. I've had plenty of opportunity to do so, but I'll disagree with saying other languages (I think you mean frameworks here) don't have superior solutions.

Comment: @Matt: No I meant what I said, the cross-platform behavior/nature, the optimal use of available reactors (select, epoll, kqueue etc), the overall design, the functionality, no language or framework for any language comes even close to what ASIO provides. I think as C++ programmers we are very luck indeed - its not very often we get such a well designed/usable library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're making asychronous calls, you have to post requests to the io_service. In your case after the `"x.connect();"` you should call `"ios.run();"`

Just remember if you don't make any further posts after the async callback returns, run will exit/return.

btw in `"ios.dispatch(boost::bind(onM, data));"` is onM meant to be onMe ?

Comment: connect is not asynchronous, async_connect is.

Comment: OnM is the method that is local to the object. I pass in a function pointer in the initialization. This also fixed my problem, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Hippocoder: Do you have any suggestions or resources for me to look at while I'm developing with boost::asio? I rather not bother SO every time I run into a small problem.

Comment: @Zoke: Look at the examples found here: http://think-async.com/Asio/  Also signup to the asio mailing list CK answers questions on that list.

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing asynchronous (`io_service::post`, `async_read_until`) and synchronous (`ip::tcp::socket::connect`, `ip::tcp::endpoint::resolve`) operations. This can work but I really do not suggest this approach. Stick to asynchronous operations, use `ip::tcp::socket::async_connect` instead of `ip::tcp::socket::connect` and `ip::tcp::socket::async_resolve` instead of `ip::tcp::socket::resolve`. You'll need to invoke `io_service::run` or equivalent, this is why your code *does nothing* after the `connect`. The Boost.Asio documentation has [numerous examples](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/http/client/async_client.cpp) showing how to achieve this.